# File upload and confirmation page before submission

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I am trying to create a "please confirm" page before submitting the data from a form. The form has a file upload field. **How do I pass the value of what is submitted in the upload field so they can confirm and click submit again?**

The rest of the data I am going to post into hidden fields and echo the values so they can confirm.

How do I accomplish this with an uploaded `$_FILE`

first page:

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="file" name="attachment"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Confirm.php

```
<form action="submit_data.php" method="post">
Your Name: <? echo $_POST['name']; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<? echo $_POST['name']; ?>"/>

//HERE IS WERE I NEED TO STORE THE FILE INFO 
Your File Name: <? echo $_FILES['attachment']['name']; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="<? echo $_FILES['attachment']; ?>"/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to process & store the image in the in the `confirm.php`. Then store a reference to the processed image:

```
// pseudo code for confirm.php
process image
  if error back to form.php
  move image to tmp directory.
inject path of tmp file into hidden field

// submit_data.php
grap temp path from hidden field.
copy to final location
```

Comment: I tried your concept but on the submit_data.php page when I reference the $tmp_path from a post variable I am getting the following error "Warning: copy(/tmp/phpFC4G3c) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in..."

Comment: on your confirm.php page you'll need to move the tmp file from /tmp/* into another directory. your http server is most likely removing this file once the page has been processed.

$newPath = 'files/somefile.upload'; copy($tmpPath, $newPath);

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript onclick function for submit in Confirm.php page like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Do you wish to upload the file");
if (r==true)
  {
 return true;
  }
else
  {
 return false;
  }
 return false;
}
</script>

<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="file" name="attachment"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"
     onclick='return show_confirm();'/>
</form>
```